# How to access a View object on a Helper anonymous class

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new in Android/Kotlin development so I will try my best to describe my problem here.
I'm trying to access Android UI thread from another thread by using the Helper object, for my Bluetooth application. From my research on internet I tried to adapt a Java code I found and I ended up with this anonymous class code on my Activity class:

```
companion object{
    var uuid : String =  "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"
    var handler : Handler = object : Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()){
        override fun handleMessage(msg:Message){
            statusMessage.text = "I called UI"
        }
    }
}
```

The problem of the code above is that I cant access any of my UI view on the `handleMessage()` function. And eventually, my connection thread can't send information to UI thread. Anyone can't give me some light or direction to solve this? Android have any other Kotlin-friendly way to communicate with UI thread?

Comment: Does this help: https://medium.com/@macastiblancot/android-coroutines-getting-rid-of-runonuithread-and-callbacks-cleaner-thread-handling-and-more-234c0a9bd8eb

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

handler.post {
  // this part of code runs on your main thread
}
```

[Handler.post()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler#post(java.lang.Runnable))